# Anybody using ruby without any framework?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, frameworks

I am experimenting with Ruby and Rails.  I like Ruby, but not Rails.  I have Java/PHP background, I have used some frameworks, but never totally liked any of them.

Anybody using Ruby to build web apps, but not any of the frameworks? (rails, merb etc).  If yes, can you point me to some resources to learn it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It might be wise to at least leverage [Rack](http://rack.rubyforge.org/), and maybe [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) gets enough out of your way for you to feel comfortable. Sinatra isn't much more than a very small, simple wrapper around the rack handler afaik.

Comment: +1 for the Sinatra suggestion. If you want a framework that gets out of your way, Sinatra is the way to go.

Answer (score 8):

Doing Web apps in Ruby without using a framework is like cooking without heat. I question the sense of trying this.

That said, you could probably hook up Apache to call a Ruby program as a [CGI](http://eregie.premier-ministre.gouv.fr/manual/howto/cgi.html). I suspect it would be dog slow, though.

**Edit:** Apparently you're not the only one crazy enough to attempt this, though: I found a tutorial on [Simple Ruby CGI](http://coolnamehere.com/geekery/ruby/web/cgi.html). The author claims as his rationale that "he has nothing better to do."

Answer (score 3):

Your question looks quite similar to [Ruby off the rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150638/ruby-off-the-rails), so you probably should read the answers of that one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ruby instead of bash and python on my ubuntu server for sysadmin tasks.

I've found Ruby a particularly clean and powerful replacement for the places I'd have previously used bash and python in sysadmin.

Answer (score 0):

I personally found one thing for myself. When I prepare some interview or I am gonna build something from scratch, in most cases I need some basic features included in Rails. That usually happens when you build something not complex, but still non trivial. In 99% of cases I need ActiveRecord, ActiveSupport etc. It is easy to get those things in your Gemfile and play with them. One thing you will always repeat is basic application structure, easy console access with preloaded libs, rakes... I created minimal gem for myself to organise this process though.. :) If you read sources you'll see what I constantly do to start something new. It is not a big deal not to use any framework at all.

https://github.com/einzige/framework