# Can Embedded Ruby Be Used Outside of Rails?

Tags: ruby, erb

Can embedded ruby (erb) be used outside of rails in regular webpages to dynamically update content (almost as a replacement for PHP)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as long as the pages are processed by a Ruby interpreter.

For instance, the [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) framework uses ERB along with other template languages such as HAML and Erubis.

Answer (score 2):

erb is part of the ruby standard library. I would recommend using [erubis](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/) if possible though, since it is significantly faster (about 3x)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Simply via CGI:
http://wiki.railsplayground.com/railsplayground/show/How+To+Use+RHTML+without+rails

Answer (score 0):

In [Ruby off the Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150638/ruby-off-the-rails/156974#156974), one person describes using ERB in a not just non-Rails, but a non-web context - using it to generate text files. I don't know how often people take that approach though.